# npm always returns this error "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.4.2":{"name":"comma' "

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, netlify

I want to publish my site via netlify so I have to install netlify-cli globally but am getting this error.
[The error that occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGlCp.png)

Comment: wats ur npm and node version?

Comment: Also make sure you have no syntax error in your package.json like dangling comms or something

Comment: node version -12.16.2 npm-version - 6.14.5

Comment: Try with `npm install -g npm@6.14.4` and check

Comment: I also experience this too often, as I observe it happens when co-dev pushes updates on package.json, and trying to npm install throws that Unexpected end of JSON. Is there any underlying issue with npm? is there something to do with package-lock.json? this is really giving headache each time. please help anyone

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g netlify-cli
```

Comment: This one helped.